# Why cant i call release version of the ubuntu container without entering inside of it from docker desktop?

Tags: docker

When i try to bring the release version the ubuntu container with command line, it seems i cant bring it but when i try to call the hosts file, it successfully works as below. Can you guys tell me the difference ?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker exec e3 cat /etc/hosts                                                                                 
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
x.x.x.x      e3ebfdc89378
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker exec e3 cat /usr/lib/os-release                                                                        
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and- 
policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker exec e3 cat /etc/*release*                                                                             
cat: '/etc/*release*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: my idea after some trying , soft link of os-release to /usr/lib/os-release cant be called by powershell docker commands probably..

Comment: Maybe they  prevent globbing at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
docker exec e3 sh -c "cat /etc/*release*"
```

Which usually enables passing wildcharacters inside container.

Comment: thx pal, it works fine as you say, it seems they totally prevent wild characters at least in powershell format.. i ll check from ubuntu as well later.